# Making a sliding puzzle game using turtle (not tkinter or pygame)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, game-development, python-turtle

So I'm currently trying to program a slidepuzzle game without importing tkinter or pygame. So far i've generated a board and populated it with working buttons (quit,load,reset) but I'm really lost on how to program the actual slide puzzle game with the images i've been provided.

This code generates the screen and buttons that makeup my board. clicking the load button (which i already have setup) allows the user to type in the puzzle they want to load and unscramble. The issue is that I don't know how to get all the images onto the board and Im not sure what direction i should go in to actually program the game elements (it's just a screen and buttons right now). I'm a newbie programmer so any help is really appreciated.

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
def generate_screen():
`os.chdir('Resources')  # Changes directory to allow access to .gifs in Resources
screen.setup(700, 700)
screen.title("Sliding Puzzle Game")
screen.tracer(0)
generate_scoreboard()
generate_leaderboard()
iconturtle = turtle.Turtle()
iconturtle.penup()
for file in os.listdir():
    screen.register_shape(file)
iconturtle.goto(280, -270)
iconturtle.shape('quitbutton.gif')
iconturtle.stamp()
iconturtle.goto(180, -270)
iconturtle.shape('loadbutton.gif')
iconturtle.stamp()
iconturtle.goto(80, -270)
iconturtle.shape('resetbutton.gif')
iconturtle.stamp()`

`def load_yoshi():
    os.chdir('Images\\yoshi')
    screen.tracer(1)
    screen.register_shape('yoshi_thumbnail.gif')
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.penup()
    t.shape('yoshi_thumbnail.gif')
    t.goto(250,290)
    t.stamp()
    screen.update()
    files = glob.glob('*.gif') # pulling out only .gif
    images = files
    print(images)
    for file in images:
        screen.register_shape(file)`
```

Comment: This is a bit broad. Can you narrow the question down to a specific technical issue? There are indentation issues you might want to fix.

Comment: I've only seen turtle used to draw lines, not shapes, much less movable game pieces. I think pygame would definitely be better for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've only seen turtle used to draw lines, not shapes, much less
> movable game pieces. I think pygame would definitely be better for
> this –  OneCricketeer

Below is an example slide game simplified from an earlier answer I wrote about creating numbered tiles using turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial
from random import random

SIZE = 4
TILE_SIZE = 100
OFFSETS = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def slide(tile, row, col, x, y):
    tile.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    for dy, dx in OFFSETS:
        try:
            if row + dy >= 0 <= col + dx and matrix[row + dy][col + dx] is None:
                matrix[row][col] = None
                row, col = row + dy, col + dx
                matrix[row][col] = tile
                x, y = tile.position()
                tile.setposition(x + dx * TILE_SIZE, y - dy * TILE_SIZE)
                break
        except IndexError:
            pass

    tile.onclick(partial(slide, tile, row, col))

screen = Screen()

matrix = [[None for _ in range(SIZE)] for _ in range(SIZE)]

offset = TILE_SIZE * 1.5

for row in range(SIZE):
    for col in range(SIZE):
        if row == SIZE - 1 == col:
            break

        tile = Turtle('square', visible=False)
        tile.shapesize(TILE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
        tile.fillcolor(random(), random(), random())
        tile.penup()
        tile.goto(col * TILE_SIZE - offset, offset - row * TILE_SIZE)
        tile.onclick(partial(slide, tile, row, col))
        tile.showturtle()

        matrix[row][col] = tile

screen.mainloop()
```

Click on a tile next to the blank space to have it move into that space:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One thing im trying to do is upload my own .gif so that instead of colors it's an actual image that's being reconstructed. Im trying to replace the line in your code tile.fillcolor(random(), random(), random()) with a for loop that runs through a list of .gif images and uses those instead. when i do the for loop it does populate with my .gifs, but it quickly runs through all of them instead of just staying on the 1 image and then generating more. Any ideas?